# Access Sharepoint via Python

Tags: python, api, authentication, sharepoint, shareplum

I try to access SharePoint via a Python Script, because I want to download and update a list in Sharepoint.

I use shareplum to access, but I get an:

> raise Exception('Error authenticating against Office 365. Error from
> Office 365:', message[0].text) Exception: ('Error authenticating
> against Office 365. Error from Office 365:', 'AADSTS53003: Access has
> been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does
> not allow token issuance.

Heres my simple Code:

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365

authcookie = Office365('https://example.sharepoint.com', username='example@mail.com', password='Password').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/example-site', authcookie=authcookie)
sp_list = site.List('list name')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you to [get client id and secret](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/wiki/How-to-connect-to-SharePoint-Online-and-and-SharePoint-2013-2016-2019-on-premises--with-app-principal)

then access sharepoint using https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/master/examples/sharepoint